# PHP Query to SQL Server through IIS 7.0 on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: php, windows-server-2008-r2, iis, sql, sql-server-2008

So I am building a webpage on my Windows Server 2008 R2, I have IIS 7 configured to work on the intranet so I can access the site locally from any machine within my Active Directory/Local Network. When I try to run a PHP script that does a basic query to let me know if the server connects. I try and run the page from both Server side and Client side (From my Workstation) and it is not working at all.

This is an example of the code I am using to establish a connection but I keep getting the error of 
"Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

Take note the fields of ServerName, UserName, Password, and DBName have been taken out for security purposes. Also all code is contained within the !DOCTYPE, HTML, and Body.

```
<?php
echo "<table style='border: solid 1px black;'>";
  echo "<tr><th>Id</th><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th></tr>";

class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator { 
     function __construct($it) { 
         parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY); 
     }

     function current() {
         return "<td style='width: 150px; border: 1px solid black;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
     }

     function beginChildren() { 
         echo "<tr>"; 
     } 

     function endChildren() { 
         echo "</tr>" . "\n";
     } 
} 

$servername = "[SERVERNAME]";
$username = "[USERNAME]";
$password = "[PASSWORD]";
$dbname = "[DBNAME]";

try {
     $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
     $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, EventID, EventType FROM dbo.Event"); 
     $stmt->execute();

     // set the resulting array to associative
     $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

     foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) { 
         echo $v;
     }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
     echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Does the MySQL system actually exist? Is the MySQL DB configured and running? Can you access it (via say MySQL Workbench) from the machine PHP runs on?

Comment: I just checked that, is the code I am running for MySQL? I do not have MySQL Server Side let, I have SQL Server Configuration Manager, Management Studio, Profiler but no MySQL.

Comment: Excuse me if I was using the wrong code. I am fairly new to this, I have minor coding experience but I was told to get this function running as a project.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. Turns out ODBC was out of date and Windows 2008 R2 required the SQL Drivers for PHP.